# How do I build when Tfs Read-only files block assembly and config file updates (via ccnet)

Tags: tfs, build-process, cruisecontrol.net, readonly

What are the work-arounds for builds failing when moved to TFS because now each file is set to read-only?

Using CC.net, TFS2008 (TFS 2010 within 2 months), target framework 3.5, msbuild 3.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an exec command to do this in the AfterGet target:

```
<PropertyGroup>
<MyProperty>D:\BuildSource</MyProperty>
</PropertyGroup>
....
<Exec Command="Attrib -r -s *.* /S /D" WorkingDirectory="$(MyProperty)" />
```

Comment: This is a decently performant solution. Does it cause any problems with the next build's attempt to get updates?

Comment: We have never experienced any issues... the workspace is recreated with each build, and the CoreClean task deletes all the files, whether they are read-only or not. The only time I've seen CoreClean fail is if someone has locked a file by leaving VisualStudio open on the build machine, for example. In general, leaving most of the files Read-only works fine for .NET bulids, so we typically would only do this for the projects that require it.  Good luck on your build! :)